# Why does this AJAX call run inconsistently?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to save reasons for people pausing their WooCommerce Subscription. I made a custom plug-in for this. A JS script runs when the user clicks pause, opens a jQuery UI dialog with a few reasons in a radio button form. Clicking 'Pause' submits the user's selection and kills the window. This works perfectly on my development website, however, it only works sporadically on my live website.

This is part of the JS:

```
$(popUpList).dialog({
            modal: true,
            width:'auto',
            text: "text",
            dialogClass: 'fancybox-container',
            buttons: {
                "Pauzeer": function() {
                    for( i = 0; i < document.pauzeerreden.cancelreason.length; i++ ) {
                            if( document.pauzeerreden.cancelreason[i].checked == true ) {
                                    var val = document.pauzeerreden.cancelreason[i].value;
                                    if(val=='other') {
                                            document.pauzeerreden.cancelreason[i].value=document.pauzeerreden.overig.value;
                                            is_other = 1;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                        $.ajax({
                      url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                      type: 'POST',
                      data: {'action': 'wcs_cancel_confirmation', 'subscription_id' : subscription_id, 'reason_to_cancel': $('input[name="cancelreason"]:checked').val(), 'is_other': is_other}
                    });
                        window.location = that.href;
                            $(this).dialog("destroy");
                        },
                "Ik wil toch niet pauzeren" : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                        }
                    }
                });
            return false;
    });
```

And this is the PHP to which it posts:

```
    if ( is_account_page() ) {
        wp_register_script( 'wcs-cancel-subscription-confirmation-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'wcs-cancel-subscription-confirmation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
        $script_atts = array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'wcs-cancel-subscription-confirmation-script', 'ajax_object', $script_atts );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wcs-cancel-subscription-confirmation-script' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcs_cancel_subscription_confirmation' );


function wcs_cancel_confirmation() {
    $subscription_id = intval( $_POST['subscription_id'] );
    $reason_to_cancel = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reason_to_cancel'] );
    $subscription = wc_get_order( $subscription_id );
    $email = $subscription->get_billing_email();
    $is_other = $_POST['is_other'];

    $note_id = $subscription->add_order_note( apply_filters( "wcs_cancel_confirmation_note_header", __( "Reden van pauzeren:", "wcs-cancel-confirmation" ) )."<br /><b><i>".$reason_to_cancel."</i></b>" );

    $subscription->save(); }
```

The code works, what are the reasons that it only works sometimes on my live website? Please let me know if you need a larger part of the JS code, I tried to slim it down as much as possible.

It shows this in the server logs for when the call does not run:

```
[Sat Apr 27 18:19:15.040960 2019] [error] [pid 27049] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(860): [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx:62308] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: -- $action = Array\n(\n    [url] => /mijn-account/view-subscription/111573/?subscription_id=111573&amp;change_subscription_to=on-hold&amp;_wpnonce=ae31aa4954\n    [name] => Pauzeren\n)\n\nPHP message: -- $action = Array\n(\n    [url] => https://fridaymascara.com/mijn-account/?subscription_renewal_early=111573&subscription_renewal=true\n    [name] => Vervroegen\n)\n\n'
[Sat Apr 27 18:19:26.783134 2019] [error] [pid 27049] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(860): [client xx.xxx.xx.xx:62311] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: -- $action = Array\n(\n    [url] => /mijn-account/view-subscription/111573/?subscription_id=111573&amp;change_subscription_to=active&amp;_wpnonce=da371dce3c\n    [name] => Opnieuw activeren\n)\n\n'
```

However, the same is logged for calls that do actually run. Judging from the error log, something isn't entirely correct about the PHP code or .htaccess file?

Comment: It would be helpful to know *how* it doesn't work. Do you see anything on the server logs? In the browser console?

Comment: Hmm, see post for what it shows in the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

The cause ended up being the page reloading before the AJAX call was completed!